# Getting error when try to use animate function

Tags: jquery

I am trying to scroll down to a specific row using this code,

```
var temp = "1000";
$(document).animate({scrollTop: $("'tr[data-id=\"" + temp + "\"]'").offset().top}, 'slow');
//also tried .position().top}, 'slow');
```

but getting this error,

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
>   'tr[data-id="1000"]'

Html

```
<tr data-id="1000" class="Row" onclick="LoadA(1000)"></tr>
```

Comment: `'tr` should just be `tr`, and `]'`, `]`

Comment: thanks, it gives me error - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefiened

Answer (score 0):

Problems with the quotes. Try this:

```
$('tr[data-id="' + temp + '"]')
```

I always prefer to play with `'` and `"` rather than escaping them.

Result:

```
$('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('tr[data-id="' + temp + '"]').offset().top
}, 'slow');
```

Comment: @CustomizedName you had more error, please check it again. Try also with negative top.

Comment: thanks, it gives me error - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefiened

Comment: i tried this approach as well, i get same error :( sorry

Comment: @CustomizedName no, you are not... This is the living example. Console is clean when executing it: http://jsfiddle.net/9dZPv/2/